# One-line generator that acts like reduce but yields all intermediate results

Tags: python, generator, reduce, recurrence

I love how easy it is to implement all kinds of commonly used high-level algorithmic behavior in Python.

I am now looking for an optimal way of implementing [recursive sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecursiveSequence.html) or any other kind of generator whose next value depends on O(1) of the most recently generated previous values.

I.e. is it possible to implement the following `reduceGenerator` in a single line (possibly using the existing [`reduce` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce))?

### Example

#### Generator

```python
def reduceGenerator(f, iterable, initialValue):
    it = iter(iterable)
    value = initialValue
    for x in it:
        value = f(value, x)
        yield value
```

#### Use case:

The following generates the sequence `(a * s[i-1] + b) mod m`:

```python
s = reduceGenerator(lambda prev, i: (a * prev + b) % m, range(N), s0)
s1 = next(s)
s2 = next(s)
```

Comment: Hmm, you can implement almost anything in a single line, but is it worth it? You already have a readable function here. Why do you want to squash it into a single line?

Comment: You might be able to do a generator like `(value := f(value, x) for x in iterable)` using the very recently added *assignment expression* feature.

Comment: It already exists as [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

Comment: I don't think a generator function should return a final value.

Comment: @coldspeed because we can!

Comment: @MikeRobins yeah, I also realized that the final `return` did not make any sense at all :)

Comment: @DanD. exactly what i'm looking for! Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: "can" and "should" are two different things...

Comment: @coldspeed turns out that my curiosity for an alternate solution has yielded to me `accumulate`, a python native that I was not aware of. The way I see it, this question was worth asking.

Comment: Consider self-answering your question, with the solution you found!

Comment: @coldspeed Credit goes to Dan D. Gonna wait for him to post the answer. Thanks for your encouragement and input!